# Building to Building Internet access

Tags: wireless-networking

Having 2 Buildings separated by around 500 meters.
I have a internet DSL conncetion in Building 1.I would like to give internet to the Building 2 wirelessly. Can anyone tell me what devices do I need to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

You can chose wireless routers with maximum range to cover that distance (considering there is no huge interference between the 2 buildings).

Also, if you have some spare old wireless routers, you can use them as repeaters to boost the reach of your DSL connection upto the 2nd building. You can follow the procedure here:

http://lifehacker.com/5563196/turn-your-old-router-into-a-range+boosting-wi+fi-repeater

Answer (score 0):

500 meters is like 1500 feet.  There is no single normal device I know of that can transmit that far.  You will need at least one if not 2 wireless repeaters.  Going more than 500 feet between repeaters will probably result in a bad quality of service.  The even standard Ethernet(Cat 5/6) has a stated max of 300m.  Fiber optic cable is the only thing that will do it with ease.

Honestly, I think, depending on interference, you may need as many as 5 wireless repeaters and each one needs a power source.  I have never seen a wireless router capable of a good connection at 1000 feet.  Many claim 1000 feet, but the signal is usually so weak that the packet drops will make it a nightmare to use.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are looking for a [Wireless Bridge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_bridge) like [this](http://www.gnswireless.com/GNS1151_5.8GHz_Short_Range_Wireless_Ethernet_Bridge.htm) one. It connects two network segments over a distance of up to half a mile. You can find as well other products if you search for wireless network bridge.